# Eigenvectors and proving cyclic vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

I am looking for help with these 2 questions. I thought (a) would be easy but its not working for me.

I thought that if its linearly independent, I should be able to come up with something like $Ax - kx = 0$ then $Ax = kx$ and then magically its an eigenvector.

For part (b), I'm not really sure but do I have to use linear independence again? ie $v + T(v) + T^2(v) + ... = 0$

EDIT: for (b), I am thinking to use the contrapositive to prove the reverse (if $x=0$)

Comment: You should be able to solve (a) by applying the definition. What can you conclude if the subspace ${\rm span}\,(v,Tv)$ is one-dimensional ?

Comment: the basis will only have one vectors. But this doesn't help me actually because then S is just span(v)

Comment: If the subspace spanned by two vectors is one-dimensional, then one of these vectors is a multiple of the other. Hence $Tv=\lambda v$ for some coefficient $\lambda.$

Comment: Ahh ok very nice. So i can just define the basis to have 2 vectors (but linearly dependent!)

Comment: Not exactly. The notion of the basis require linear independence.

Comment: What if i use span instead of basis? Im letting the span be (v, T(v))

Comment: Then it's OK. The spanning set of vectors may be redundant, i.e. some of the vectors can be  linear combinations of other vectors.

Comment: Ok great, I have a strong understanding of part (a) now. What about part (b)?

Comment: Observe what is going on with $S_{T,v}$ when the first coordinate $x$ of $v$ is equal $0.$  Next assume that $x\neq 0.$ Show that $v,Tv,T^2v$ are linearly independent, thus they span the whole space.

Comment: As an alternative approach, note that $v$ is cyclic relative to $T$ iff it is cyclic relative to $T-I$ (where $I$ is the identity transformation).